# Can't sign in to Azure to publish with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to test Azure by publishing a basic web app. After signing in to Azure from Visual Studio, I'm met with the following message:

> Sorry but we didn't find any Windows Azure subscriptions associated with your account.
>
> You can sign in with a different account or sign up for a Windows Azure subscription.

I use Windows 8 with an attached ecu account, and have signed up to a trial Azure account under the same credentials (which I can log in to normally fine).

Results[1] from a similar problem suggest the accounts are mixed up, and to contact an admin with the ticketing system to rectify[2]. However selecting "Having issues with sign in or signing up for an account?" links me to a page, which quickly redirects me to another broken page and I am unable to proceed.

What is the best course in action in either:

1. publishing the app to Azure
2. contacting Microsoft about fixing my trial Azure account

Thank you

[1] http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b61b9a9-e763-4893-acc1-aa60a7d0b03d/msdn-subscriition-free-access-to-windows-azure-cannot-setup-account?forum=windowsazurepurchasing

[2] http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on social.technet.microsoft.com

I found this article first, so I hope this helps others that find this before the MS article.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/40ac7a3d-12f0-47c5-9cee-97dd5867ddf0/unable-to-sign-in-when-trying-to-publish-web-role-to-azure?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I was recently having a problem with visual studio 2015 where I could not sign in to Azure. I came across this SO entry.  It was not helpful, but I eventually did find the answer.

The answer was to repair Visual Studio. It takes awhile to run but once it finished I was back in business with Azure in Visual Studio.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396